# how to put two navigation buttons on imageview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to know how to put two overlapped navigation buttons on ImageView. To make clear, I want to previous and next navigation buttons in ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this layout to wrap your `image` with two `buttons` above it on the top left corner.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bbuttonLeft"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Marked as correct answer but found duplicate layout_width attribute.

Answer (score 1):

why using `ImageView` you can use a `Layout` and set it's background. and then put the buttons as you wish.

if you insist on using and `ImageView`

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_height="..."
  android:layout_width="...">

  <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
  <!-- put the buttons in here as you like -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `ImageView` into `RelativeLayout` and use `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView".